# how to add color to primitive string in flutter

Tags: flutter

want to know the simple way to add color in primitive string.
I have a primitive string something like below and i want to color it without adding any widget

`String s = "this is a string";  // i want to color this string`

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible. It would be better if you could tell what you want to do with that String and how you want it to behave inside your application. Because ```String``` can't hold values of ```Color``` in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is a widget in Flutter. You should really just wrap your String in a Text and use the style property to change the color of the String. But what is your main goal by doing so ?

Comment: @I know i can do that. i just wanted to know  there is any way to colorize the string and after that i can use the colorize string to concate with other string

Comment: It's not possible as far as I know, but a useful widget to do this kind of operation is the RichText Widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html). By using TextSpan, you will be able to customize the color of each segment @kundefine

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(yourString,
style: TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xFF**Your hex code**)
),),
```

Comment: adding an explanation will be very helpful to future users